# Regex - Select Link and everything before/after

Tags: html, regex, yahoo-pipes

With all the questions already asked on this topic unfortunately I was unable to combine all the information into a working Regex.

I'm trying to use **yahoo pipes** to substitute the *content* of an RSS post with a link that was previously contained in this post (HTML format).

Within the post there are various links but only one link with the **url** and **parameter** I am looking for. I'm trying to extract **`.txt`** and **`.pdf`** files, the expression for filetype is lazy because there are more links to pdf/txt files later on and I want only the first link to be selected (from what I understood, if I don't make it lazy the text up until the last occurence of the filetype will be selected).

The links are embedded as follows:

```
...Previous Link</a> – <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://url.net/file/folder/filename.parameter.txt/pdf">description</a> – Next Link <a rel...
```

I need all Text before/after this link selected because I'm substituting the whole selection with the actual plain-text Link.
What I've come up with so far is:

```
((.|\n)*)(http://url.*parameter.*?(txt|pdf))((.|\n)*)
```

It does work in Regexr: http://regexr.com/3argq
But unfortunately results in the following error when put in yahoo pipes:

> unable to complete regex operation

How should I proceed ahead?

Comment: Hello. What is "PARAMETER" is uppercase? Is it supposed to be in the link?

Comment: I wrote it in uppercase letters to make it more visible, that was before I was suggested to write it bold. The whole link is written in lowercase letters.
And yes, parameter is supposed to be in the link and thus has to be included in the REGEX as there are always two or more links with the same url.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the slashes - instead of `//` write `\/\/`

Comment: Unfortunately the error persists even though I applied the changes you recommended. Upon further research I found out that Yahoo Pipes is written in Java and some Errors can occur due to Regex Syntax being slightly different in Java - could that have something to do with the problem at hand?